# Rxjs, combineAll()

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, как работает следующий код:

```
of("a", "b", "c")
  .pipe(
    map(x => interval(2000).pipe(take(2))),
    combineAll()
  )
  .subscribe(vl => console.log(vl));

// Result:
//[0, 0, 0]
//[1, 0, 0]
//[1, 1, 0]
//[1, 1, 1]
```

Как я понимаю - на первом этапе для каждого эмита ("a", "b", "c") с интервалом в 2 сек выбирается 2 первых значения (0,1).

Что происходит дальше, как вообще формируется массив?

След. этап - combineAll берет последние значения обзервеблов и эмитит в сабскрайб массив этих последних значений.

Запуталась вкрай, помогите.

Comment: твой код идентичен -> `combineLatest([ interval(2000).pipe(take(2)), interval(2000).pipe(take(2)), interval(2000).pipe(take(2)) ])`. Т.е. `of(a, b, c).map(-> interval)` просто создает 3 стрима - `interval.pipe(take(2))`. `combineAll` под капотом напрямую делегирует работу `combineLatest`. `combineLatest` подписывается на 3 стрима и генерирует значения от них в виде массивов. В самом начале он ждет генерации значения от 3х стримов, поэтому ты получаешь `[0,0,0]`, а потом генерирует массивы отдельно, в зависимости от генерации значения от каждого стрима

Comment: @overthesanity, спасибо!)

Comment: @overthesanity, кажется, ваш комментарий можно превратить в ответ)